# Troca de Usuarios

Tags: c#

Pessoal Boa Noite estou fazendo um projeto na Faculdade e deparei com um problema a um tempo e não consegui resolver. Tenho a tela de Login e dentro do sistema tenho Troca de Usuário e quando chamo a tela de Login ele abre um outro sistema em cima com o que estava sendo usado embaixo, quando fecho a aplicação anterior fecha tudo, fiz com que a autenticação feche a tela atual e abre uma nova só que quando fecha a aplicação anterior aguarda a confirmação de fechamento sim ou não tem alguma coisa que posso resolver isso ?

O código a baixo é do botão do menu chamando a tela login do usuário, o código comentado é o teste que fiz com um exemplo da internet mais não deu certo

código:

```
    private void trocarUsuarioToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmLogin objLogin = new frmLogin();
        objLogin.MdiParent = this;
        objLogin.Show();

        //this.Visible = false;
        //frmLogin objLogin = new frmLogin();
        //objLogin.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está meio confusa, tente colocar um trecho de código referente a cada passo que você está explicando para facilitar o entendimento. @denilson-carlos

Comment: Creio que a minha resposta te ajude a resolver seu problema, para conhecer um pouco mais de como funciona o SOpt faça um [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente existe mais de uma maneira de se fazer isso, vou te passar um exemplo de base e você altera conforme as suas necessidades.

Formulário de Login:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Aplicativo.Teste
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        // propriedade para indicar se a autenticação foi feita com sucesso.
        public bool Autenticado { get; private set; }

        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Autenticado = false;
        }

        private void btnAutenticar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // essa verificação é somente para exemplificar
            if (txtSenha.Text == "123456")
            {
                Autenticado = true;
                Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Senha inválida.", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                txtSenha.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Formulário do Menu:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Aplicativo.Teste
{
    public partial class frmMenu : Form
    {
        // propriedade para indicar se foi feito o logoff.
        public bool Logoff { get; private set; }

        public frmMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Logoff = false;
        }

        private void btnLogoff_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logoff = true;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Classe com o método *main*:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Aplicativo.Teste
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            frmLogin fLogin = null;
            frmMenu fMenu = null;
            bool logoff;

            do
            {
                logoff = false;
                fLogin = new frmLogin();

                Application.Run(fLogin);

                if (fLogin.Autenticado)
                {
                    fLogin.Dispose();
                    fLogin = null;

                    fMenu = new frmMenu();

                    Application.Run(fMenu);

                    logoff = (fMenu != null ? fMenu.Logoff : false);

                    fMenu.Dispose();
                    fMenu = null;
                }

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            } while (logoff);
        }
    }
}
```

O código está bem simples e fácil de entender, caso você ainda tenha alguma duvida deixe nos comentários.